# отправка письма с файлом на почту

Tags: php, phpmailer

Не приходят письма на почту, вроде и ошибок нет, как не старался изменять, не работает.
Вот код обработчика может кто подскажет:

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$exp = $_POST['exp'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'login'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'parol'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров
$mail->setFrom(''); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 

$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['name']);    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);   
                                // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .'ФИО:'.$name.'\r\nВозраст: '.$age.'\r\nВозраст: '.$age.'\r\nСтаж вождения: '.$exp.'\r\nРайон проживаният: '.$place.'\r\nРайон регистрации: '.$reg.'\r\nТелефонт: '.$phone.'\r\nEmailт: '.$mail;
$mail->AltBody = '';
$mail->send();

?>
```

Comment: что $mail->send() возвращает ?

Comment: я почему то не  к нему достучатся, я пытался echo отлаживать, но он мне ничего не выводил в какое бы место я его не ставил, но у меня есть проще формы которые работают, но там echo тоже не работает, тоже не понимаю почему

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете класс PHPMailer и записываете его в $mail, потом в $mail вы записываете $_POST['mail']. Естественно дальше у вас все отваливается, что бы избежать таких затруднений, настройте вывод ошибок в php

```
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$exp = $_POST['exp'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'dmitro_bolva@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'ghbdtnlbvjy22081996'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров
$mail->setFrom('dmitro_bolva@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress($email);     // Кому будет уходить письмо 

$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['name']);    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);   
                                // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .'ФИО:'.$name.'\r\nВозраст: '.$age.'\r\nВозраст: '.$age.'\r\nСтаж вождения: '.$exp.'\r\nРайон проживаният: '.$place.'\r\nРайон регистрации: '.$reg.'\r\nТелефонт: '.$phone.'\r\nEmailт: '.$mail;
$mail->AltBody = '';
$mail->send();
```

Comment: сейчас попробую исправить

Comment: никак не повлияло на работоспособность скрипта( хотя да  там была ошибка не досмотрел